Use GPG in Python with PyNaCl
I am trying to play with GPG and PyNaCl.
I can get to import the Key in Python with the gnupg CLI wrapper python-gnupg and know it's response is base64 encoded.
import base64
import gnupg


key_id = "..."
gpg = gnupg.GPG()
public_key = "".join(gpg.export_keys(key_id).split("\n")[2:11])
public_key = base64.b64decode(public_key)

But then this is not the pure ED25519 key and I cannot just import it with:
import nacl
nacl.signing.VerifyKey(public_key)


What processing do I need to do to only get the public key? I played a bit with gpg -a --export ... | gpg --list-packets, but I don't understand its output.

Once I will have that, I will want to also sign messages. I will do this with gpg directly:
data, passphrase = ...
signature = gpg.sign(data, keyid=key_id, passphrase=passphrase, detach=True).data
base64.b64decode(signature)


Is this the pure signature without extra metadata?

